# `map` equivalent to 2d list comprehension

Tags: julia, list-comprehension

In 1d, I can use either of these:

```
[i for i in 1:5]
```

or

```
map(1:5) do i 
    i
end
```

both produce

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Is there a way to use `map` in higher dimensions? e.g. to replicate

```
[x + y for x in 1:5,y in 10:13]
```

which produces

```
5×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 11  12  13  14
 12  13  14  15
 13  14  15  16
 14  15  16  17
 15  16  17  18
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
julia> map(Iterators.product(1:3, 10:15)) do (x,y)
         x+y
       end
3×6 Array{Int64,2}:
 11  12  13  14  15  16
 12  13  14  15  16  17
 13  14  15  16  17  18
```

The comprehension you wrote is I think just `collect(x+y for (x,y) in Iterators.product(1:5, 10:13))`, . Note the brackets `(x,y)`, as the `do` function gets a tuple. Unlike `x,y` when it gets two arguments:

```
julia> map(1:3, 11:13) do x,y
         x+y
       end
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 12
 14
 16
```

Comment: It looks like you got the ranges partially flipped from the example. The example in the question uses `x=1:5` and `y=10:13`, and your example uses `x=1:3` and `y=10:15`. This gets a little confusing when comparing the outputs of the question and the answer. :)

Comment: Yes, I changed them, twice in fact.

Comment: `@code_lowered (() -> ([x + y for x in 1:5,y in 10:13]))()` agrees with this answer :)

Answer (score 5):

This, of course, is not the `map` equivalent that you are looking for, but in some cases like this you can use broadcasting with a vector and a transposed vector:

```
x = 1:5
y = (10:13)'
x .+ y
```

At the REPL:

```
julia> (1:5) .+ (10:13)'
5×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 11  12  13  14
 12  13  14  15
 13  14  15  16
 14  15  16  17
 15  16  17  18
```